# vue v-if="isEditable" @click.prevent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have

```
Vue.component ('test', {
template: '<div 
    '@click="imageHelperClick($event)"  ' +
    '@mouseout="mouseoutHelper" ' +
    'class="el-hover image-hover" :data-div-id="helper.htmlId">' +
    '<transition name="fade"><span v-if="helper.mouseover">Press to load image</span></transition>' +
    '<size-check-input ref="fileInput" type="file" data-upload-check @change="imageSelected($event)" accept=".eps,image/x-png,image/jpeg"/>' +
    '</div>',
methods:{...},
```

And I want to make that div clickable if `helper.isEditable==true` else notClickable, touchable, etc.

Complexity in that, I'd get that parameter only when document.ready and server send me information about field `isEditable`.

So, my question is:

Can I make

```
computed:{
isEditable: function(){
return helper.isEditable;
}
}
```

and then do something like

```
v-if = "isEditable" @click.prevent @mouseOver.prevent 
v-else @click="imageHelperClick($event)" @mouseout="mouseoutHelper"
```

etc?

Comment: Are you just looking for the syntax to make something not clickable?
If so, have you tried `@click.stop="true"`?

Comment: Yes, i tried that, But I need something that can prevent/stop all changing

Answer (score 0):

Vue dont have syntax like that. You could try

```
:disabled="yourFlag"
```

and toggle `yourFlag` to make it clickable or not

Comment: I`m looking for something that can stop any focus/click/mouseover from my template when flag "isEditable" ==false. As I understand, :disabled cancel any changing only for 1 method, but is there any method which cancel any changing?

Comment: I made @mouseout="mouseoutHelper"  :disabled="fromSet" and nothing changed(
I added console.log() into my method and it see that mouseover/mouseout from element, but I still can change my element

Comment: But, If i do that :disabled=true , its work, suddenly